# Consequence of xsl:value-of as child of xsl:variable

Tags: xslt

What is the differences between these three blocks in terms of side-effects when `$world` is a list of elements? I am seeing a different behaviour between the first and the third and cannot get my head around it.

```
<xsl:variable name="hello" select="$world" />

<xsl:variable name="hello">
    <xsl:value-of select="$world" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="hello">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$something=true()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$world" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$world" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Edit 1: I want to process `$hello` in a `<xsl:for-each select="$hello">`. With the third block above the `<xsl:for-each>` has only one item to process that contains the joined contents of `$world`. Why is that?

Comment: Side effect has a special connotation in declarative paradigm... Rephrasing title.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation of your problem and an example of complete XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `xsl:variable` will have the same value and type as `$world`. The second is a result tree fragment with a single text node of the string value of `$world`. The third is also a result tree fragment with a single text node.

I guess you want either

```
  <xsl:variable name="hello" select="if (condition) then $world else $foo"/>
```

in XSLT 2.0 and then your `for-each select="$hello"` would work as you want or in XSLT 1.0 plus EXSLT common you want

```
<xsl:variable name="hello">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="condition">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$world"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$foo"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($hello)/*">...</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin. Can I conclude that there is no way to get what I want in XSLT 1.0 without EXSLT?

Comment: @Martin Honnen: _"a single text node of the string value of"_ [ **first node in** ] _"$world."_ [ **node-set** ].

Comment: @Fabian Wickborn: Declaring a variable with one or another node set is a FAQ: `<xsl:variable name="hello" select="$world[$something]|$moon[not($something)]"/>`

Comment: You haven't provided much details. It might be that e.g. `<xsl:variable name="hello" select="$world[foo = 'bar']"/>` does what you want, meaning an XPath filter predicate applied to your original variable is sufficient. But it depends on the kind of condition you want to check and how it relates to the nodes. There are certainly things were XSLT without exsl:node-set can't achieve the goal in a single transformation step.

Comment: Alejandro, Fabian said "contains the joined contents of $world" so there could be a chance that he uses XSLT 2.0 that's why I was intentionally not precise on that issue.

Comment: Alejandro, thanks for pointing out that this is FAQ. In the real-world application for which I needed help there is no such simple thing as a variable like `$world` but instead a much more complicated expression that somebody else wrote and which I needed to maintain. I intentionally stripped down the example to the bare minimum (or, at least, to what I thought was the bare minimum) thereby inventing the existence of `$world`. Since this has been my first contact with XSLT my knowledge of the underlying existence is close to non-existing.

Answer (score 1):

While all three examples are valid in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0, the way the semantics are described is very different in the two specs; also when $value contains multiple nodes, the effect of `<xsl:value-of select="$value"/>` depends on whether the stylesheet specifies version="1.0" or version="2.0".

The main things to remember, that apply to both versions, are (a) xsl:value-of creates a text node by converting whatever it selects into a string, and (b) xsl:variable with contained instructions (and no "as" attribute) creates a new tree rooted at a document node.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   <xsl:variable name="hello">
>       <xsl:choose>
>           <xsl:when test="$something=true()">
>               <xsl:value-of select="$world" />
>           </xsl:when>
>           <xsl:otherwise>
>               <xsl:value-of select="$world" />
>           </xsl:otherwise>            
>          </xsl:choose>        
>     </xsl:variable>
> ```
>
> I want to process `$hello` in a
>   `<xsl:for-each select="$hello">`. With
>   the block above the `<xsl:for-each>` has
>   only one item to process that contains
>   the joined contents of `$world`. Why is
>   that?

The variable named `$hello` contains the string value of `$world`. This is by definition how `<xsl:value-of>` behaves in XSLT 1.0.

You haven't shown us how `$world` is defined, but if it contains a single element or a whole document tree, then (again) by definition, its string value is the concatenation (in document order) of all of its descendents - text nodes.

This is exactly what you are seeing.

**The situation will be different if insead of**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$world" />
```

**you use**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$world" />
```

This copies the whole subtree whose root is the element (or root node `/` in the case when `$world` contains a complete document) contained in `$world`.

However, in XSLT 1.0 this creates the so called RTF (Result Tree Fragment) and by definition one cannot use an RTF as a location step in XPath (1.0) expression.

One must first convert this to a regular tree (document node) using a vendor-supplied extension function that most often has the local-name `node-set` but is in a vendor-specific namespace.

**A typical example is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vWorld" select="/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfHello">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vWorld"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vHello" select=
   "ext:node-set($vrtfHello)/*"/>

  <xsl:copy-of select="$vHello/*[3]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the result is** (as expected):

```
<num>03</num>
```

Here we use the `ext:node-set()` extension function in the namespace "http://exslt.org/common" as specified by the EXSLT vendor-independent library. Most XSLT 1.0 processors support EXSLT and using its `node-set()` extension function doesn't decrease the degree of portability of an XSLT application accross all such XSLT processors.